# INSERT SQL Updatable Query using proper MS Access cmd Command

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2013, sql-insert, ms-access-2013

Access databse query fails when i run on another machine Config Below

**Microsoft Word 2013
Visual Studio 2013
Windows 8.1 (64 bit)**

While On The Another Machine The Same Query Runs Config Below

**Microsoft Word 2010
Visual Studio 2010
Windows 7 (32 bit)**

The Query Below

```
 con.Open();

            string cb = "insert Into Salcmd = new sqles(InvoiceNo,InvoiceDate,CustomerID,SubTotal,VATPercentage,VATAmount,GrandTotal,TotalPayment,PaymentDue,Remarks) VALUES ('" + txtInvoiceNo.Text + "',#" + dtpInvoiceDate.Text + "#,'" + txtCustomerID.Text + "'," + txtSubTotal.Text + "," + txtTaxPer.Text + "," + txtTaxAmt.Text + "," + txtTotal.Text + "," + txtTotalPayment.Text + "," + txtPaymentDue.Text + ",'" + txtRemarks.Text + "')";
            cmd = new OleDbCommand(cb);
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                con.Close();
            }
            con.Close();
```

is there something wrong with the Query Dependencies Please Let Me Know

Comment: Can you post the error message?

Comment: 1) Syntax Error in Insert into Statement 
2) Operation Must Use an Updateable Query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You INSERT SQL statement contains a syntax error:

```
string cb = "insert Into Salcmd = new sqles(InvoiceNo,InvoiceDate,CustomerID,SubTotal,VATPercentage,VATAmount,GrandTotal,TotalPayment,PaymentDue,Remarks) VALUES ('" + txtInvoiceNo.Text + "',#" + dtpInvoiceDate.Text + "#,'" + txtCustomerID.Text + "'," + txtSubTotal.Text + "," + txtTaxPer.Text + "," + txtTaxAmt.Text + "," + txtTotal.Text + "," + txtTotalPayment.Text + "," + txtPaymentDue.Text + ",'" + txtRemarks.Text + "')"
```

It possibly should be:

```
string cb = "INSERT INTO sqles(InvoiceNo,InvoiceDate,CustomerID,SubTotal,VATPercentage,VATAmount,GrandTotal,TotalPayment,PaymentDue,Remarks) VALUES ('" + txtInvoiceNo.Text + "',#" + dtpInvoiceDate.Text + "#,'" + txtCustomerID.Text + "'," + txtSubTotal.Text + "," + txtTaxPer.Text + "," + txtTaxAmt.Text + "," + txtTotal.Text + "," + txtTotalPayment.Text + "," + txtPaymentDue.Text + ",'" + txtRemarks.Text + "')"
```

Also, try: `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` instead of reader.

Hope this may help.

Comment: Include the Error Message in your question. Best regards,

Comment: Thankyou Very Much Sorted